# Character rotate at collider with camera script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a simple script for the Camera to follow a Player target.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

// LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

but when I start the game the player starts rotating and ignores colliders when hitting a collider for the first time.

[image]

This started happening after I have put this script on the player. I even tried to freeze the rotation but if I freeze the rotation I can not rotate my player with animations. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script to the 'Camera' not the 'Player'  and you should be just fine.